# Can't respond to messages in message request in fbchat

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to make a bot so that when someone sends it a message the bot sends back a joke but I've noticed this only works with people in my friends list but if random people sent to the bot then their message gets stuck in message request on messenger and even the fbchat library recognizes this and tells me in the console that there is a new pending message so is there a way to respond to those too?

Here is my code:

```
from fbchat import Client,ThreadLocation

class JokesBot(Client):
    def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
        self.moveThread(ThreadLocation.PENDING,thread_id,thread_type)
        self.markAsDelivered(thread_id, message_object.uid)
        self.markAsRead(thread_id)

        # If you're not the author, echo
        if author_id != self.uid:
            self.send(Message(text='wiso tefl hehe'), thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=thread_type)



client = JokesBot('email', 'password')

client.listen()
```

Bare in mind I still didn't implement the jokes so it's missing from the code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**onMessage** event called only when connected facebook friend sends you a message.

for unconnected facebook users(not friends) you should use another event **onPendingMessage** but unlike onMessage' in pending message things are getting more complex:
take a look at fbchat [documentation](https://fbchat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/fbchat/_client.html#Client.onPendingMessage)

after the event called you should call the method: "fetchThreadList" in oreder to see the incoming message